# Kotlin - unresolved reference for constant

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to use the sample code of the new camera hardware API (android.hardware.camera2) for my android app. First, I converted the Java code to Kotlin code by the automatic conversion feature of the Kotlin plugin for Android Studio. Below is a piece of the converted code:

```
private val mCaptureCallback = object : CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

    private fun process(result: CaptureResult) {
        when (mState) {
            STATE_PREVIEW -> {
            }// We have nothing to do when the camera preview is working normally.
            STATE_WAITING_LOCK -> {
                val afState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE)
                if (CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState || CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState) {
                    // CONTROL_AE_STATE can be null on some devices
                    val aeState = result.get<Int>(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE)
                    if (aeState == null || aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED) {
                        mState = STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE
                        captureStillPicture()
                    } else {
                        runPrecaptureSequence()
                    }
                }
            }
            STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE -> {
                // CONTROL_AE_STATE can be null on some devices
                val aeState = result.get<Int>(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE)
                if (aeState == null || aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE || aeState == CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED) {
                    mState = STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE
                }
            }
            STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE -> {
                // CONTROL_AE_STATE can be null on some devices
                val aeState = result.get<Int>(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE)
                if (aeState == null || aeState != CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE) {
                    mState = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN
                    captureStillPicture()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the unresolved reference error for:

```
CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED
CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED
CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED
CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE
CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED
```

But these constants are recognized in the original Java code. There's any solution for these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These variables are declared in CameraMetadata. In Kotlin static variables and methods cannot be called on subclasses.

Comment: No, just use CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED instead of CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED